# Sqlite database not created when using android studio

Tags: sqlite, cordova, android-studio, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make a small app using Cordova. Trying to simply insert some values in the sqlite database. But I am not able to `create`, nor `insert` anything. I am very much new to android studio. I tried to run the same code on eclipse and xcode and it worked correctly! I used sqlite-local storage plugin

Here is my Code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
    name: "DMS"
  });
  db.transaction(function(tx) {

    // tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF  EXISTS tblUserLoginDetail ");
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblUserLoginDetail (UserId INTEGER , Username VARCHAR ,Password VARCHAR )");

    alert("Creating table");
    // tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO  tblUserLoginDetail (UserId,Username,Password) values (1,"kamayani","kam12")",[],function(){alert("success");},function(){alert("error");});

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tblUserLoginDetail (UserId, Username,Password) VALUES ("1", "Firstrow","kkk")');

  });

  $("#btnSignIn").click(function() {
    //
    //ValidateUser();
    alert("onClik");
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
      name: "DMS"
    });
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("select * from tblUserLoginDetail", [], function(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        var row = results.rows.item(0);
        var UserDetail = row['UserId'] + "-" + row['Username'];
        alert("MeetingName" + UserDetail);

      }, function() {
        alert("error");
      });


    });
  });
}

function errorCB(err) {
  alert("Error" + err.code);
}
```

What happens is it shows all the alerts like "Creating table" and then shows the onclick alert .. but then i cannot find the database in the file explorer of Android studio! Am I missing something?

I have added the plugin inside the assets-->www-->plugins folder and given a link to Sqliteplugin.js in the html file.

Comment: included Cordova.js file in your HTML?

Comment: Yes I did. I included cordova.js file. Also i tried to run some online sample sqlite code in a newly created cordova project but that also does not work. To be precise, the app_databases folder in file explorer does not create DMS.db

Comment: As per the official github page of sqliteplugin, in opendatabase() we are supposed to specify db file name like this - var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'}, successcb, errorcb); But i dont see location specified in yours and also the name is DMS, shouldnt it be DMS.db?

Comment: As per i know, .db extension is taken by default and the code works in eclipse.  But I shall give this a shot!!

Comment: you can also take care of location:default setting

Comment: Even after adding default location, i cannot find the db.Am i using proper plugin (sqlite-local storage).

Comment: I know its quiet long to get back. But after spending time on this, i gotta know to that we cannot view .db file straightforward. We gotta root the device or use some other technique. But i came out with a sample app for you which you can download and test it directly after installing the plugin. The link is as follows - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_SQLite

Comment: In case of emulators, database can be seen through file manager of android studio. I had already done that on eclipse. Thanks a lot for this! :)

Comment: I uninstalled the latest version of cordova sqlite plugin and installed an older version and issue was resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its quiet long to get back. But after spending time on this, i gotta know to that we cannot view .db file straightforward. We gotta root the device or use some other technique. But i came out with a sample app for you which you can download and test it directly after installing the plugin. Please check out this [link](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_SQLite)